# Query based on object type

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to get a list of objects based on foreign object type (not value)

To make sample i just wrote 6 simple class that simulate my problem.
In short, i would like to get all users where their activity location is a type of School

```
 public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public Activity Activity{ get; set; }
}

public class Activity
{
    public int IdActivity { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Location
{
    public int IdLocation { get; set; }
    public string Xy { get; set; }
}

public class Indoor : Location
{
    /// props
}

public class External : Location
{
    /// props
}

public class School : Location
{
    /// props
}
```

Comment: You've misspelled school btw

Comment: And propbably name of activity property

Comment: What is this "foreign object type (not value)" you're talking about and can you show how your list would look like? If it is just `List<User> myList` or something similar, have you tried to use a `.Where(...)` call? Take a look at LINQ maybe: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, i made some naming mistake, as i mentioned just wrote 6 classes in notepad, sorry for the confusing and thanks for the comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply check location type with `is` operator:

```
users.Where(u => u.School.Location is School)
```

If it's possible that some activity can be without location, then you can use null-conditional operator to avoid NullReferenceException:

```
users.Where(u => u.School?.Location is School)
```

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, all the misspellings in the OP confused me :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
IEnumerable<User> schoolUsers = myUsers
    .Where(user => user.School.Location is School);
```